# Do Firebase Hosting only host static file / asset?

Tags: web, ember.js, firebase

I am newbie in web development. And I am working on ember with firebase using emberfire.

As I found that I can deploy the ember project to Firebase hosting, do firebase hosting support asset hosting only? And I have to host my ember web project in another hosting?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Ember requires NodeJS (npm) installed on your hosting to work. Firebase Hosting doesn't have anything like that.</strike>

Point of correction: Ember.js is a front-end tool like AngularJS, therefore you *can* use it with Firebase, which supports only static files hosting.

Firebase Hosting only stores assets (css, js and images files) and doesn't have any form of installing serverside packages.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Firebase Hosting documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/):

> Firebase Hosting provides fast and secure **static** hosting for your web app.

Embjer.js is a front-end only framework. Web applications built using Ember.js can be run on Firebase Hosting.

Give it a try and report back if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

fast forward to 2019, firebase now offers functions where you can write dynamic code for your static app. It uses node (express.js).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases

Comment: Just to clarify, firebase functions are a separate service and are running in a different NodeJs environment. Firebase hosting still can ONLY serve static assets. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct @DevsloveZenUML